# Multi line list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert multi line list to a pandas df. Each list is created from multiple json files by paring the key value. Here how it looks.

```
['Hello', 'This', 'Is', 'a', '', '95', 'ML', 'file', 'that', 'needs', 'tobe', 'parsed', 'and','all the paragraph', 'should', 'be','captured' 'for','comp1']
['hi', 'This', 'line', 'a', '', '100', 'ML', 'file', 'that', 'needs', 'tobe', 'parsed', 'and','all the paragraph', 'should', 'be','captured' 'for','comp222222']
```

When I am converting it, each line becomes one index, but in reality each list should be one index. In this case, index 0 and index1.
It would be like,

```
    colname=text
0 Hello This Is a  95..
1 hi This line a ....
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = ['Hello', 'This', 'Is', 'a', '', '95', 'ML', 'file', 'that', 'needs', 'tobe', 'parsed', 'and','all the paragraph', 'should', 'be','captured', 'for','comp1']
l2 = ['hi', 'This', 'line', 'a', '', '100', 'ML', 'file', 'that', 'needs', 'tobe', 'parsed', 'and','all the paragraph', 'should', 'be','captured', 'for','comp222222']

all_lists = [l1, l2]

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Text': ' '.join(l)} for l in all_lists])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                Text
0  Hello This Is a  95 ML file that needs tobe pa...
1  hi This line a  100 ML file that needs tobe pa...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There would be one column name Text. So, I am trying to put all the string in a single column. sorry for the confusion. I should have elaborated more

Comment: I want like this.colname=text
0 Hello This Is a  95..
1 hi This line a ....

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. It's currently giving me the same. but want to wrap all the text in a single line/paragraph

Comment: @cloudroy Now it should be ok :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Much appreciated for the help.